# The expected edge length of a cube is equal to $e_{D}(f) = f^{1/D}$, why is that?

Tags: probability, geometry, statistics, machine-learning

section 1.4.3 of the book "Machine Learning - A Probabilistic Perspective" gives an example about KNN:

the input is two dimensional, we have three classes, and K = 10

[image]

[image]

[image]

here is Figure 1.15

[image]

here is Figure 1.16

[image]

> the expected edge length of this cube

$e_{D}(f) = f^{1/D}$

why is that? is this formula an existing formula in geometric?

Comment: You ask a very similar question somewhat later at [The expected edge length of a cube is equal to $e_{D}(f) = f^{1/D}$, what is the definition of `the expected edge length`?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3306368/the-expected-edge-length-of-a-cube-is-equal-to-e-df-f1-d-what-is-the). In future similar situations, please include a link to the later question as a courtesy to help avoid people duplicating efforts. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how you define the "expected" edge length of the cube without knowing the algorithm by which the cube is grown, but it is true that if data are randomly scattered according to a uniform distribution inside a $D$-dimensional hypercube of unit edge length,
a $D$-dimensional hypercube with edge length $f^{1/D}$ inside the unit hypercube is expected to contain $f$ times the total number of data points.

This follows from the fact that the expected number of uniformly-distributed points in a given volume inside the unit hypercube is proportional to the volume.
That is, if you construct a region that encloses half the total volume of the unit hypercube, you expect it to contain half the points distributed within the unit hypercube.

The volume of the unit hypercube is $1.$ The volume of a hypercube of edge length $s$ is $s^D.$ If you have a hypercube of edge length $s = f^{1/D}$, the volume of that hypercube is $(f^{1/D})^D = f.$

Comment: OP cited this "Suppose we estimate the density of class labels around a test point x by “growing” a hyper-cube around x until it contains a desired fraction f of the data points." is that not the `algorithm` you are asking for?

Comment: "Growing ... until" is not an algorithm. An algorithm would say _how much_ we grow the cube each time in each direction. I would guess that a very careful algorithm (growing _just enough_ to enclose the last required point, possibly growing more in one direction than the opposite direction) would capture $f$ portion of the data in less than $f$ portion of the volume. But not _much_ less volume, and the reduction in edge length would be even less dramatic, again due to the curse of dimensionality. It's a detail that doesn't really make a difference.