# The expected edge length of a cube is equal to $e_{D}(f) = f^{1/D}$, what is the definition of `the expected edge length`?

Tags: probability, geometry, machine-learning

section 1.4.3 of the book "Machine Learning - A Probabilistic Perspective" gives an example about KNN:

the input is two dimensional, we have three classes, and K = 10

[image]

[image]

[image]

here is Figure 1.15

[image]

here is Figure 1.16

[image]

> the expected edge length of this cube

$e_{D}(f) = f^{1/D}$

what is the definition of `the expected edge length`?

Comment: It is a peculiar formulation. Look at it this way: The probability that a random sample lies in a given cube with edge length $e$ inside a unit cube is $e^D$ (its volume). So from a set of samples $s_1, \ldots, s_N$ the expected number of samples in the given cube is $e^D N$, i.e. a fraction of $e^D$.

Comment: @czlsws You asked a very similar question somewhat earlier at [The expected edge length of a cube is equal to $e_{D}(f) = f^{1/D}$, why is that?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3306041/the-expected-edge-length-of-a-cube-is-equal-to-e-df-f1-d-why-is-that). In future similar situations, please include a link to the earlier question as a courtesy to help avoid people duplicating efforts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There the fraction $f$ is ment to give the $D$-dimensional volume of some "expected hypercube", which is designed such that it contains this point subset. If $s$ is the side length of the hypercube, then its volume is given by $s^D$. When equating those 2 values and solving for $s$ you'd just get $s=f^{1/D}$.

--- rk